# How to Play Avi, Flv File in backend magento

Tags: magento, jwplayer, shadowbox

I have a custom module in which i add video files from my magento back-end to a specific album. Files are uploaded locally or embedded through URL. To view already uploaded files I added a link from which user can play the Current Uploaded file or can be played through saved URL and 'File Browse Button' to upload a new one. I have used Shadowbox and jwplayer for this purpose. From URL video just played fine but for locally uploaded file if it is in AVI Format, both players didn't work for AVI format

Here is My Code

JWPlayer which can't support Avi Format

`jwplayer('sb-body-inner').setup({
      file: url,
      width: '380',
      height: '270',
      autostart: 'true',
      image: img,
      });`

and Shadow Box Player

`Shadowbox.init({
     handleOversize: 'resize',
    flashVars: { 
    skin: '".Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'mediaappearance/skin01.zip'."',},
    overlayOpacity: 0.8,
    });`

Also My anchor tag is from which i call jwplayer or shadowbox

```
    `<a href="'.$withfunction.'" rel="'.$videoRel.'">View current file</a>'`
```

Thanks in Advance for help

Here is the Screen Shot to better explain my case
[Add Media Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxgEk.jpg)

Comment: You can see error in firebug window

Comment: Why are you using 2 players to play files ? I think 1 could be enough with all file types support i-e Shadowbox

Comment: how can i play all the files like mp4 swf through shadowbox player

Comment: Use Shadowbox.open function set the player and ext options as you need. Hope it will help

Comment: Can you explain this or share the code how can i use the ext and player option

Comment: JW Player does not support AVI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of all the file types you want Shadowbox to play included avi,flv etc

`var FileTypesToPlay = {                                                flv:['flv'],
qtwmp:['avi', 'mpg', 'mpeg'], 
qt:['dv', 'mov', 'moov', 'movie', 'mp4'],
};`

And write the Shadowbox.open like that

`Shadowbox.open({
content: 'Your File Path Url',
players: [ 'flv', 'qt',  'qtwmp']
ext: '+FileTypesToPlay+'
});`

Read the Shadowbox documentation also : http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html